# Laravel spatie custumize model_has_roles table

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I changed *model_has_roles* table.I added **domain_id** in *model_has_roles* table there is no problem with that.
Now, I have one user with two domain. For instance, i have jhon doe in abc.com role with admin and also jhon doe in xyz.com role with editor. When i use `Auth::user()->roles`  function, function returns both admin and editor roles. i want roles according to domain which i want.

**custom model_has_roles table**

| role_id | model_type | model_id | domain_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | App\User | 2 | 17 |
| 6 | App\User | 2 | 16 |

Comment: Add a unique constraint to the columns

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you find an answer but if it's not, you can look at https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/teams-permissions

You can define `'teams' => true`,
`'team_foreign_key' => 'domain_id'`

And after, in your Home controller, or other middleware which check role and permission, you can add this :
setPermissionsTeamId(domain_id);